# set session cookie secure and httpOnly for LFR_SESSION_STATE_%

Tags: java, jboss, liferay-6.2, cookie-httponly

Environment :

1. Liferay 6.2 with Jboss

We are trying to implement httponly and secure.

For this we have dome some changes like below

> Added in Portal-ext.properties :
>
> ```
> cookie.http.only.names.excludes=
> ```

and

> Added following properties in ROOT.war/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
     <session-config>
      <cookie-config>
       <http-only>true</http-only>
       <secure>true</secure>
      </cookie-config>
     </session-config>
```

I can see all the session cookies are httponly except the one which are starting with ***LFR_SESSION_STATE_***

Can anyone suggest how we can handle this.

Answer (score 2):

LFR_SESSION_STATE_ are cookies that explicitly get handled on client-side and not on server side - thus they're inherently only accessed through JS. As far as I know they're never even persisted on server side. And I don't expect any real leakage from these cookies. In my perception the cookies are about determining state of the quality "should this help item be shown with full text or just collapsed".